# Reading an Xml to the DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, linq

What is the efficient way to read the following xml file to a DataTable. I am not able to 
get the duplicate project data.

```
<Employees>

<Employee>
    <EmployeeID>25</EmployeeID>
    <Project>
        <ProjectId>1001</ProjectId>
        <STARTDT>2008-08-18</STARTDT>
    </Project>
</Employee>

<Employee>
    <EmployeeID>26</EmployeeID>
    <Project>
        <ProjectId>1002</ProjectId>
        <STARTDT>2009-11-09</STARTDT>
        <ENDDT>2013-11-04</ENDDT>
    </Project>
    <Project>
        <ProjectId>1003</ProjectId>
        <STARTDT>2013-11-05</STARTDT>
    </Project>
</Employee>

</Employees>
```

The expected result

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
EmployeeId    ProjectId     StartDt          EndDt
-------------------------------------------------------------------
25             1001        2008-08-18
26             1002        2009-11-09
26             1003        2013-11-05
```

Comment: Can you add how  your DataSet and Datatable definition look like?

Comment: Are you loading the XML to a `DataTable` just to find the duplicates? If so, you could probably also locate them using `LinqToXml` via `XDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

Read it into a `DataSet`:

```
String xml = "<Employees><Employee><EmployeeID>1328911000001108</EmployeeID><Project><ProjectId>5000456001090</ProjectId><STARTDT>2008-08-18</STARTDT></Project></Employee><Employee><EmployeeID>1330611000001103</EmployeeID><Project><ProjectId>5017007023913</ProjectId><STARTDT>2009-11-09</STARTDT><ENDDT>2013-11-04</ENDDT></Project><Project><ProjectId>5017007019213</ProjectId><STARTDT>2013-11-05</STARTDT></Project></Employee></Employees>";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(xml), XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

Key here is `XmlReadMode.InferSchema` which will produce two tables in the DataSet, linked by `EmployeeID`.